# Reading an arbitrary number of bytes from a bytearray in a loop

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I have data contained in bytearrays as blocks of bytes. Doing this only reads one byte at a time :

```
for byteValue in byteString:
    doSomething(byteValue)
```

How could I make a similar structure that reads **n** bytes at a time, and stops when StopIteration is raised ? (*if possible, with a for loop as well*)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's many ways to do what you want. Here's a relatively simple one that works by treating the byte *string* as a byte *stream* and then uses a combination of the built-in [`iter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#iter) function and [`functools.partial()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) to process it in blocks of `n` (or less) bytes at a time.

It's important to note how the optional *`sentinel`* argument that the `iter()` function supports — the `b''` value — is being used to cause a `StopIteration` to be raised when the end of the stream is encountered.

```
from functools import partial
from io import BytesIO


byteString = b'Cras mollis mauris vitae libero ornare finibus Donec nibh odio'
n = 4

byte_stream = BytesIO(byteString)
for block in iter(partial(byte_stream.read, n), b''):
    print(block)
```

Output:

```
b'Cras'
b' mol'
b'lis '
b'maur'
b'is v'
b'itae'
b' lib'
b'ero '
b'orna'
b're f'
b'inib'
b'us D'
b'onec'
b' nib'
b'h od'
b'io'
```

Comment: What about variable length ? I suppose I would have to wrap ```byte_stream.read``` in some other way ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying about variable length. `N` can be anything and simply tells the `BytesIO.read()` method the maximum number of bytes to read, You can vary it as you see fit.

Comment: It's kind of hard to explain, but I think I know how to do it

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good way other than loading the entire array and then slicing it. This isn't a problem if you've already got the bytearray in memory, but if you're reading it from a file, is less memory-efficient.

```
blockSize = 4
byteString = bytearray("abcdefghijkl", encoding="utf-8")

for i in range(len(byteString), blockSize):
    print(byteString[i:i+blockSize])
```

Alternatively, you could accumulate the bytes in a separate bytearray.

```
n = 0
while n < len(byteString):
    bbytes = [byteString.pop(0) for i in range(blockSize)]
    n += len(bytes)
```

Or, if byteString is an iterator, such as from a `open('...', 'rb')`,

```
with open('myfile.bin', 'rb') as bf:
    while True:
        bbytes = bf.read(blockSize)
        if not bbytes:
            break
```

Comment: That last solution might actually do what I want ! It's a shame there isn't an easier way to redefine what the **for** loop does